# What is the best node module for uploading pictures to Amazon S3 services?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to find a good npm module that uploads picture files from the browser to Amazon S3. There are so many modules for amazon web services I'm not sure which one is most widely used or the best. Can anyone recommend a module?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Express CDN](https://github.com/niftylettuce/express-cdn) is a good node module for making use of Amazon S3 services.